# Using unapply defined in traits

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, unapply

I have a trait

```
trait A {
    def doSomething(a: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] = {
        a.map {
            case AA(s) => s // want to use unapply defined in trait (this(AA) not allowed)
            case _ => "idc"
        }
    }
    
    def unapply(a: Int): Option[String] = getString(a)

    
    def getString(a: Int): Option[String] = {
        a match {
            case 1 => Some("one")
            case 2 => Some("two")
            case _ => None
        }
    }
}

object AA extends A
object AA2 extends A {
    override def getString(a: Int): Option[String] = {
        super.getString(a).orElse{
            a match {
                case 3 => Some("three")
                case 4 => Some("four")
                case _ => None
            }
        }
    } 
}

object MyClass {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(AA.doSomething(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))); // Output: List(one, two, idc, idc, idc)
        println(AA2.doSomething(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))); // Expect Output: List(one, two, three, four, idc) but get List(one, two, idc, idc, idc)
    }
}
```

The problem here is I can't use the unapply defined in the trait without creating an extractor object.

I would like to override the getString method in different objects using this trait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a self type to reference yourself.

```scala
trait A { self =>
  final def doSomething(a: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] =
    a.map {
      case self(s) => s
      case _       => "idc"
    }

  final def unapply(a: Int): Option[String] =
    getString(a)

  def getString(a: Int): Option[String] =
    a match {
      case 1 => Some("one")
      case 2 => Some("two")
      case _ => None
    }
}
```

Which works as expected.

---

*Code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/MnpHz3HGSKSerX5sSoVwaw)*.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I used was

```
trait A {
    def doSomething(a: Seq[Int]): Seq[String] = {
        a.map {
            case Extractor(s) => s
            case _ => "idc"
        }
    }
    
    object Extractor {
        def unapply(a: Int): Option[String] = getString(a)
    }

    
    def getString(a: Int): Option[String] = {
        a match {
            case 1 => Some("one")
            case 2 => Some("two")
            case _ => None
        }
    }
}

object AA extends A
object AA2 extends A {
    override def getString(a: Int): Option[String] = {
        super.getString(a).orElse{
            a match {
                case 3 => Some("three")
                case 4 => Some("four")
                case _ => None
            }
        }
    } 
}

object MyClass {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(AA.doSomething(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))); // Output: List(one, two, idc, idc, idc)
        println(AA2.doSomething(Seq(1,2,3,4,5))); // Output: List(one, two, three, four, idc)
    }
}
```